# Insert Document Type in xslt transformation

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have an XSLT that transforms a picture library and turns it into a jQuery galleria control.
I can make it work in a standard html page, but I have the need to put it in a Sharepoint 2007 web-part, so the content type is not available:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
```

Is there a way I can assign this to the page using XSLT, Javascript or otherwise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

XSLT does that

```
<xsl:output
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" 
/>
```